# Calculate rate from log file timestamps

Tags: log-files, text

From postfix's logfile I can *grep* all the lines that indicate the delivery of one message:

```
Jan  3 15:28:21 mail postfix/pipe[1040]: [...] status=sent
Jan  3 15:28:21 mail postfix/pipe[1157]: [...] status=sent
Jan  3 15:28:22 mail postfix/pipe[980]: [...] status=sent
```

I'd like to group them together by timestamp, so I can calculate the messages per second for a given time range. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$ cut -d " " -f 4 postfix.log  | sort -n | uniq -c
```

If you want to select a given time range, just throw another `grep` before this with your desired regex.